Cold Bee and Old Beer
Introduction:
Inspired by this silly meme video, which states 'COLD BEER', but is slightly too large for the scrolling advertisement board, causing it to display either 'COLD BEE' or 'OLD BEER' instead.
Challenge:
Given a dictionary-list of words, output all ordered pairs of words which can form new words if you'd remove the first letter of the first word in the pair and last letter of the last/second word in the pair.
Or, perhaps a more straight-forward explanation and implementation approach:

Filter the input-list so all words with its first letter removed form a new valid word from the list.
Filter the input-list again so all words with its last letter removed form a new valid word from the list.
Take the cartesian product of these two filtered list, to create a list of all ordered pairs of these words (making sure to not use the same word twice!).

Challenge rules:

I/O is flexible.
It's possible there are no valid pairs to be made from the input, in which case the result is an empty list.
The output pairs should be ordered. So with the example, ["cold","beer"] is valid, but ["beer","cold"] is not (unless eer and col both would have been part of the input-list as well).
The input-list won't contain duplicates. But make sure to not use a single word as a pair. E.g. ["beer","bee","eer"] won't result in ["beer","beer"] but [] instead.

General Rules:

This is code-golf, so the shortest answer in bytes wins.
Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
Standard rules apply for your answer with default I/O rules, so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
Default Loopholes are forbidden.
If possible, please add a link with a test for your code (e.g. TIO or ATO).
Also, adding an explanation for your answer is highly recommended.

Test Cases:
Input: ["this", "is", "a", "test", "using", "the", "example", "cold", "beer", "with", "bee", "and", "old"]
Output: [["cold","beer"]]
Input: ["this", "eyes", "his", "eyesight", "eye", "is", "flow", "ear", "low", "earn"]
Output: [["this","eyes"],["this","earn"],["his","eyes"],["his","earn"],["flow","eyes"],["flow","earn"]]
Input: ["cold", "postal", "this", "his", "blow", "beer", "percentage", "old", "inside", "low", "exposed", "insider", "bee", "destiny"]
Output: [["cold","beer"],["cold","insider"],["this","beer"],["this","insider"],["blow","beer"],["blow","insider"]]
Input: ["no", "possible", "result", "here"]
Output: []
Input: ["beer","bee","eer"]
Output: []

Why isn't ["his","eyes"] in the second example? I have [["this","eyes"],["this","earn"],["his","eyes"],["his","earn"],["flow","eyes"],["flow","earn"]] for that one.

recommended test case: ["cold","beer","old","bee","hosts","ghost","ghosts"]

From the first test case, wouldn't "this" and "is" be correct? They would give "this i" and "his is". Or have I misunderstood?

@Adám Oops, you're completely correct. I've fixed it.

@AaronF i isn't part of the input-list. And from this to is you're also removing two letters instead of just one.

@KevinCruijssen thanks! now a new day has dawned I can see what I couldn't last night :-)

Jelly, 11 bytes
œ!2ḊṖƭ€fƑ¥Ƈ

Try it online!
Don't love resorting to ƭ for this.
œ!2            Permutations without replacement of 2 elements.
          Ƈ    Filter the pairs to those which
       fƑ      are unchanged by filtering to the wordlist
         ¥     after
   Ḋ ƭ€        removing the first character of the first word
    Ṗ          and the last character of the second.


Python 3, 59 bytes
lambda d:[[i,j]for i in d for j in d-{i}if{i[1:],j[:-1]}<d]

Try it online!

Haskell, 54 bytes
f w=[[x,y]|x<-w,y<-w,x/=y,elem(tail x)w,elem(init y)w]

Attempt This Online!

Charcoal, 34 32 bytes
ＷＳ⊞υιＦυＥΦυ¬∨⁼ικ⁻⟦Φιν✂κ⁰±¹⟧υ⁺⁺ι κ

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
ＷＳ⊞υι

Input the words.
Ｆυ

Loop over all of the words.
ＥΦυ¬∨⁼ικ⁻⟦Φιν✂κ⁰±¹⟧υ⁺⁺ι κ

Loop over all of the words except where both words are the same or either the suffix of the first word or the prefix of the second word are not present in the list.

R, 76 69 bytes
Edit: -1 byte thanks to @int 21h -- Glory to Ukraine --.
\(W,`?`=\(i)W[sub(i,"",W)%in%W],x=merge(?"^.",?".$"))x[x[,1]!=x[,2],]

Attempt This Online!
The final filtering condition looks ugly to me, but I can't think of anything shorter.

-1 byte by replacing substr withsub+regex

@int21h--GlorytoUkraine-- nice idea, thanks!

Brachylog, 15 bytes
{⊇Ċp.bʰkᵗ∈ᵛ?∧}ᶠ

Try it online!
Explanation
{              }ᶠ      Find all:
 ⊇Ċ                     Take a couple of 2 words [a, b] from the input
   Ċp.                   Output is either [a, b] or [b, a]
     .bʰkᵗ               Remove the first letter of a and the last letter of b
                         (or vice-versa if the output is [b, a])
          ∈ᵛ?∧          Verify that these 2 new words are in the original input


Arturo, 55 bytes
$->_[permutate.by:2_|select'p->_⊃@[drop p\0chop p\1]]

Requires modern Arturo, hence the online playground won't run this yet. Here's a screenshot of running this locally:

Explanation
$->_[...]        ; a function taking an arg named _
permutate.by:2_  ; get permutations of length two
|                ; then...
select'p->       ; select pairs p where...
_⊃               ; the input is a superset of...
@[...]           ; a list with...
drop p\0         ; first word in pair w/o first letter
chop p\1         ; second word in pair w/o last letter


Ruby, 58 bytes
->w{w.permutation(2).select{|a,b|[a[1..-1],b.chop]-w==[]}}

Try it online!

Perl 5 -a, 84 bytes
$"=',';map{/(.(.*)),((.*).)/;say if$1ne$3&&(grep$2eq$_,@F)*grep$4eq$_,@F}<{@F},{@F}>

Try it online!

Japt, 14 12 bytes
I'm stupidly out of practice; I'm sure there's a better way.
ï
f@m¸øX¸s1J

Try it

Dart, 206 204 bytes
List<dynamic>f(var l){var x=[];for(var i=0;i<l.length;i++)for(var j=0;j<l.length;j++)if(l[i]!=l[j]&&l.contains(l[i].substring(1))&&l.contains(l[j].substring(0,l[j].length-1)))x.add([l[i],l[j]]);return x;}

Goes through all pairs of words, checks whether they're a valid pair, returns the answer as a list of pairs.
Previous (thanks Kevin for -2 bytes):
List<dynamic>f(var l){var x=[];for(var i=0;i<l.length;i++)for(var j=0;j<l.length;j++)if(l[i]!=l[j])if(l.contains(l[i].substring(1))&&l.contains(l[j].substring(0,l[j].length-1)))x.add([l[i],l[j]]);return x;}


The two if-conditions can be combined by changing the second )if( to an additional &&. Also, I do't know Dart too well, but perhaps all && can also become & using bitwise-ANDs?

05AB1E, 12 bytes
ãʒÙ`¨s¦‚åJT-

Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
ã            # Cartesian product to create all possible pairs of the (implicit) input-list
 ʒ           # Filter it by:
             #  For valid pairs:
  Ù          #   Uniquify, which is a no-op for valid pairs
   `         #   Pop and push both words separately to the stack
    ¨        #   Remove the last letter from the top word
     s       #   Swap so the first word is at the top
      ¦      #   Remove the first letter of this word
       ‚     #   Pair the two strings together
        å    #   Check for both strings whether they're in the (implicit) input-list
         J   #   Join this pair of checks together
          T- #   Subtract 10
             #   (only 1 is truthy in 05AB1E)
             #  For pairs using the same word twice:
  Ù          #   Uniquify, so a singleton remains
   `         #   Pop and push this word to the stack
    ¨        #   Remove the last letter from this word
     s       #   Swap so the (implicit) input-list is at the top of the stack
      ¦      #   Remove the first string from the list
       ‚     #   Pair the list together with the word
        å    #   Check for each inner string whether they're in the (implicit) input-list
         J   #   Join the inner list of checks together
          T- #   Subtract 10 from values in the pair
             #   (a pair will always be falsey, since only 1 is truthy in 05AB1E)
             # (after which the list of valid pairs is output implicitly)


F#, 168 bytes
let p(d:string seq)=Seq.allPairs(d|>Seq.where(fun w->Seq.contains(w.Substring 1)d))(d|>Seq.where(fun w->Seq.contains(w.Remove(w.Length-1))d))|>Seq.where(fun(f,l)->f<>l)

Gets the two sets of words, pairs them with Seq.allPairs, and finally removes the duplicates. Had to use some strong typing, otherwise there would be compiler errors.
Try it online!

JavaScript (Node.js), 77 bytes
f=(x,a)=>x.flatMap(b=>a!=b&x.includes(b.slice(!a,a&&-1))?a?[[a,b]]:f(x,b):[])

Try it online!
-3B from Arnauld

a?-1:1/0 could be just a&&-1

jq, 93 bytes
. as $L|def m(f):map(select(f|IN($L[])));[m(.[1:]),m(.[:-1])]|combinations|select(.[0]!=.[1])

Attempt This Online!
. as $L |                     # Bind the full list to $L
def m(f):                     # Function m selects all elements which are in
  map(select(f | IN($L[])));  # the list after applying the given filter

[m(.[1:]), m(.[:-1])]         # Generate lists of possible first and second words
| combinations                # Take the Cartesian product of the two lists
| select(.[0] != .[1])        # Filter out any ["foo","foo"] cases

